# Why I cannot create standalone object of HttpURL in pydantic?

Tags: python-3.x, object, pydantic

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, HttpUrl
from typing import Optional

class TestClass(BaseModel):
    url:Optional[HttpUrl] = None
```

Creating object TestClass with url="https://www.test.com" works.

Here the imported HttpUrl or BaseModel are class. When I try to create httpurl object standalone it gives typeerror e.g. below.

```
from pydantic import HttpUrl

myurl = HttpUrl("https://www.test.com")
```

Why it cannot be used to convert string to http object like above. It results
errors like: need keyword-only args if that is provided then 2 positional provided required 3

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Thanks ewong for looking in this thread traceback was quite common like typing error: keyword argument required or less number of arguments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPD 2023-10-30 (thanks [Christoph H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10027628/christoph-h))
In Pydantic 2 you should use a TypeAdapter, since parse_obj_as was deprecated.

```py
ta = TypeAdapter(HttpUrl)  
url = ta.validate_strings("test.com")
```

(**Only Pydantic 1.X**) You can use parse_obj_as method. This way there will be fewer dependencies:

```py
from pydantic import parse_obj_as, HttpUrl  
url = parse_obj_as(HttpUrl, "https://www.test.com")
```

Comment: In Pydantic 2 you should use a TypeAdapter, since parse_obj_as was deprecated.
ta = TypeAdapter(HttpUrl)
url = ta.validate_strings("https://www.test.com")

Answer (score 2):

pydantic types are valid only when used as a class variables inside `BaseModel` derivatives.

Under the hood, pydantic [fires](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/cc54acb612cb5144a34caebb9ac143324a0cb4a1/pydantic/networks.py#L222) `validate` method of `AnyUrl` class which is inconvenient for external usage.

Maybe `urllib` library will come handy for you?

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
myurl = urlparse("https://www.test.com")
```

Comment: Thanks, I observed that. However we still create stand alone object with HttpUrl with mandatory parameters like. HttpUrl(url=url,schema='',host='')

Answer (score 1):

In Pydantic version 2 you should use the following code, because parse_obj_as is deprecated:

```
from pydantic import TypeAdapter, AnyHttpUrl

url = TypeAdapter(AnyHttpUrl).validate_python("https://www.test.com")
```